# RecyclerView - Shifting layout when creating item divider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing a vertical divider for each of my viewHolders using itemDecoration. How would I make it so the layout draws the dividers first, and then it draws the views to the RIGHT of the dividers?

```
@Override
public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {



    int top = 0;
    int bottom = parent.getHeight();


    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        parent.getLayoutManager().getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, this.mBounds);
        int right = 150;
        int left = 0;
        this.mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        this.mDivider.draw(c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override [`getitemoffsets()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration#getitemoffsets_1) as well. There you apply offsets to the items:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(
                Rect outRect,
                View view, 
                RecyclerView parent,
                RecyclerView.State state
) { outRect.left = 150; }
```